# What is the plural of “café au lait“?

Tags: word-choice, plural-forms

According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+caf%C3%A9+au+lait%2Ctwo+caf%C3%A9+au+laits%2Ctwo+caf%C3%A9s+au+lait&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20caf%C3%A9%20au%20lait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20caf%C3%A9%20au%20laits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20caf%C3%A9s%20au%20lait%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctwo%20caf%C3%A9%20au%20lait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20caf%C3%A9%20au%20laits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20caf%C3%A9s%20au%20lait%3B%2Cc0) "café au laits" is more common.

On Google Books, however, [cafés au lait](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two%20caf%C3%A9s%20au%20lait%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) is quite common.

Which plural form is more common? (Especially in the US?)

Comment: You need to check the results, for example I found: "Sandrine poured coffee into **two** café-au-lait **bowls**” and then the other examples are focused on skin birthmarks "Patient with **two** café au lait **spots**” https://www.ctf.org/images/uploads/PossibleNF1_CafeAuLaitSpots.pdf

Comment: Are you talking about English or French here?

Comment: The second is correct French, the first treats the whole phrase as a loanword and makes it follow English rules.

Comment: @WS2 I'm talking about English.

Comment: @KateBunting So which one would you use in correct English?

Comment: As I speak French, I would probably use the French version (I don't remember ever having had occasion to write it!)

Comment: @KateBunting - moi aussi !

Comment: People drink cafés au lait in the US? News to me...

Comment: @KateBunting - 'Quand je suis entrée, il y avait deux cafés au lait dans la salle' - a quoted racist remark by a French person (they were _métisses_). But in Spanish _due café con leche_.

Comment: We do say café au lait at times in the states. It's found, for example, in coffee shops that are not Starbucks. There are thousands of small coffee shops and they all have their own creative lingo.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's *dos cafés con leche*, **due** is Italian.

Comment: @Lambie - quite right.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *Café-au-lait* is not necessarily racist in French. It is merely the name of a color here. It is however likely racist in the sentence you quote. It is also misspelled, it should be *café-au-lait* with hyphens when referring to a color and not a drink, and as such, it is also invariable in French., e.g. *des peaux café-au-lait* (not *cafés-au-lait*.)

Comment: @jlliagre - I copied the text from a French discussion; the spelling is that of the author. Would a racist say 'Il y avait deux noir dans la salle' or 'deux noirs'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, the Internet is full of spelling mistakes, especially when they are not obvious like that one. About *deux noirs dans la salle*, all depends on the context. Sometimes, *black* is used to avoid saying *noir* (*Il y a deux blacks dans la salle*) but it is becoming controversial. Using *noir* or *black* might not be more (or less) racist that saying *Il y a deux blancs dans la salle*, however, saying *Il y a deux jaunes dans la salle* would be very offensive.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey By the way, I checked and in fact both *café au lait* and *café-au-lait* are valid spellings when referring to the color but regardless of the hyphens, no plural mark is expected.

Comment: @Lambie In the UK you will seldom hear *café-au-lait* used. Away from the modern "coffee awfuls", we have our own tradition of naming coffee - *black or white* - the latter being with milk.  Only when we are in France do we use *café-au-lait*.

Comment: @WS2 Café au lait is not the same as coffee with milk because the lait (milk) part is heated in France, if you buy it in a café or even if you drink it at home. The milk is heated. Yes, there are places in the states where we say white or black, also. But the milk is **never** heated.

Comment: @Lambie In an upmarket hotel, or restaurant in the UK they will serve warm milk with coffee and still ask you if you want black or white? The term *café-au-lait* belongs to the 1950s when establishments tried to appear posh by putting the menu in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, the literal English translation of 'cafe au lait' is 'coffee with milk'. If we were using the English, we would say:

- One coffee with milk
- Two coffees with milk

However, 'cafe au lait' as a loan from French is a *compound noun*, therefore it is quite acceptable to pluralise the entire noun:

- Two cafe au laits.

This is because we are asking for 'cafe au lait' as a complete item, not for coffee to be served with milk. For comparison, note that the British dish 'Fish and Chips' is never pluralised as 'fishes and chips'. Native speakers would ask for "two fish and chips", or "fish and chips twice".

As to which is more 'popular' - to be honest, it probably isn't used often enough in English to be dogmatic about that. In the UK, where France is our near neighbour, we are well aware of the term but don't really use it. There are more Italian loanwords used, like *caffe latte*. This also seems to be the case in US coffee chains, which are also present in the UK.

Comment: Café au lait has heated milk. Coffee with milk is not heated, typically. And in France, in a café, café au lait is served in a cup. Generally, the bowl thing is in people's homes, not at a café.

Comment: @Lambie That's partly irrelevant, and partly wrong. The direct translation is irrelevant. Many loanwords are used differently to their original language meaning. Cul-de-sac, for example. It's also wrong, as 'coffee with milk' in many parts of the UK *does* mean coffee (often instant) made entirely with hot milk instead of water.

Comment: Actually, it isn't because the translation is: coffee with heated milk, if you care about being precise and actual meaning. You posted the translation, not me. Generally, "would you like a coffee? Or: some coffee? Yes. How do  you take it? With milk or black? By definition, café au lait comes with heated milk. It is not made with it. And finally, the bowl thing in France is in people's homes. Not in a café.

Comment: @Lambie As usual you're being hypercritical and adding nothing to the answer. 1. You have failed to notice I expressly stated *literal translation*. The literal translation is not always the meaning in any language. 2. I know what a cafe au lait is, my family lived in France for 12 years. 3. You're completely hung up on the French meaning when this question and answer is about English. The meaning of it is not in question. I merely brought up the literal translation to make the point that it would be pluralised differently if we read it that way, but we don't.

Comment: You said: "If we were using the English, we would say", one coffee with milk. I am not hypercritical. You just missed the specifics on this. So, in fact, **you are** translating and you apparently feel the idea of hot milk is not important. And café au lait is only served **for breakfast** (generally)  in bowls in people's houses.

Comment: @lambie Yes I did say that. But the perceived meaning of those words in English - as in the kind of concoction the barista will give you - is irrelevant. I was showing how, as a phrase, that would be pluralised in comparison to the way we pluralise the French equivalent which we treat as a compound noun rather than a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a question when dealing with borrowed words: *Do you follow the grammar rules of the original language, or of English?

Is "cacti" or "cactuses" the correct plural?  Should you say "2 sushi" or "2 sushis".

In more formal writing, it is common to follow the rules of the original language.  And so in books you'd expect "cafés au lait" to be common.  But in informal writing, or when representing speech in text, you'd expect "cafe au laits" to be quite common.

In fact, I'd prefer using a counter:  "Two cups of café au lait". By treating as uncountable, then problem vanishes.

Comment: I don't think the 'cup' solution is a satisfactory answer... partly because it dodges the issue rather than answer it, but also because cafe au lait isn't traditionally served in a cup, it is served in a bowl. In some places, that's all that differentiates it from a Caffe Latte.

Comment: Two bowls of cafe au lait.  But the OP asked about America where all styles of coffee are normally served in cups....Dodging the problem is the point.  I'll dodge any issue if I can!